# the eigenvalues of $X,Y,Z$ with relation $X-Y=Z$

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

J. von Neumann, Some matrix inequalities and metrization of matrix space, Tomsk Univ. Rev. vol 1 (1937), pp. 286--300.

In the above article, Neumann showed the following inequality.

Let $X,Y,Z$ be three Hermitian matrices of order $n$, with eigenvalues $$x_1\geq x_2\geq \cdots\geq x_n,\quad y_1\geq y_2\geq \cdots\geq y_n,\quad z_1\geq z_2\geq \cdots\geq z_n.$$ Assume that $X-Y=Z$. Then 
$$\max_{j_1<j_2<\cdots<j_n}\sum_{i=1}^k (x_{j_i}-y_{j_i})\leq \sum_{i=1}^k z_i,\quad 1\leq k\leq n.$$

I could not prove it. Also, I find not find the reference [J. von Neumann, Some matrix inequalities and metrization of matrix space, Tomsk Univ. Rev. vol 1 (1937), pp. 286--300].

Comment: Is there a typo? There is no reason for $y_i$ to be an integer $1$ to $n$, so 
no such thing as $x_{y_i}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes, I have corrected it.

Comment: Presumably you also want $X-Y=Z$.